postgresql update column on joining multiple tables
how to form an update query to JSONSTRING form the following select query.
The
tb_project.tf_commission ='11245'
   and tb_position.tf_name ='facility01'

are the conditions:
select   
tb_position.tf_description as description,
tb_project.tf_commission as commission,
tb_detail.tf_productid as productId,
tb_project.tf_id as projectId,
tb_detail.tf_json as **JSONSTRING**

from tb_detail

    inner JOIN tb_product ON tb_detail.tf_productid = tb_product.tf_id
    inner JOIN tb_position ON tb_position.tf_id = tb_product.tf_positionid 
    inner JOIN tb_project  ON tb_project.tf_id =  tb_position.tf_projectid 

    WHERE  
       tb_project.tf_commission ='11245'
       and tb_position.tf_name ='facility01'


How is the question related to java?

it will be used in a PreparedStatement

@Jan How it can possible affect an answer?

@ talex: is only of subordinate importance

You can use:
update tb_detail
set tf_json='JSONSTRING'
where
   tf_productid in (
select p.id as id from tb_product p
inner JOIN tb_position ON tb_position.tf_id = p.tf_positionid 
inner JOIN tb_project  ON tb_project.tf_id =  tb_position.tf_projectid 
    WHERE  
       tb_project.tf_commission ='11245'
       and tb_position.tf_name ='facility01'
) 



thank you for your help. I've got the following error message:
missing entry in FROM clause for table “tb_product”

Try changed version.

@talex: I changed the other reference to the alias too....

Here is working example https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/42gehnuex

@talex:
thanks, I can continue working with!
